# Need to create Angularjs week select calender

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am new for angularjs. Need to create a calendar to select a particular week. I found code for the same in Jquery, but I don't want Jquery code I need Angularjs  code. Can any body help me to convert the Jquery code into Angularjs code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("#weeklyDatePicker").datetimepicker({
      format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
  });

  $('#weeklyDatePicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
      var value = $("#weeklyDatePicker").val();
      var firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(0).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(6).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
      $("#weeklyDatePicker").val(firstDate + " - " + lastDate);
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9usq3enn/271/)

Thank you...

Comment: create a wrapper around jQuery library

Comment: @Satpal Not week day, entire week selecter

Answer (score 0):

If you want calendar using angular JS you can use UI bootstrap service. 
The link is bellow
[UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

If you want calendar to select a particular week you can use UI-Calendar plugin. The link is bellow
[UI-Calender](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/)

Their are multiple predefined events you can choose which event will useful to you.